# Rails http request itself in tests hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Problem**

Making an HTTP request from a model to a route on the same app results in request timeout.

**Background**

Why would you want to http request itself rather than call a method or something?

Here is my story: there is a rails app A (let's call it shop) and a rails app B (let' call it warehouse) that talk to each other over http.

I'd like to be able to run both of them in a single system test to test end-to-end workflow. Rails only runs a single service, but one can mount app B as a rails engine into the app A, effectively having two apps in a single service. However, they still talk to each other over http and that's the bit that does not work.

**Thoughts**

It *looks* as if the second request hits some kind of a thread lock around active record or something. The reason I thinking about active record, is that I was able to make an http call to itself from the controller (that is, before active record related code kicked in)

**Question**

Is it possible to work around that?

Comment: You shouldn't do real http requests on tests, even in your case where both apps run together. You can just test that method A does an HTTP request with the specific parameters and test that method B, with specific parameters, does the right thing, all in two separated specs so no real HTTP request is done.

Comment: @arieljuod I appreciate your advice, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote a comment and not an answer haha. I mean, I know it does not answer your question, but you are trying to do something that is seen as a bad testing methodology (doing real http requests on tests) and you have no real benefit testing that way.